# Adding/Removing columns based on menu selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I have a JTable; I want to provide a menu with checkboxes, one checkbox for each column in the table, to allow the user to select columns to display or hide.  I've written the following class, which almost works.

```
public class SelectableColumns implements ActionListener
{
  JTable table = null;
  JMenu  menu  = null;    public JMenu getMenu() { return menu; }

  public SelectableColumns(JTable table)
  { 
    this.table = table;
    menu = new JMenu("Columns");

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    Enumeration<TableColumn> enumerator = columnModel.getColumns();
    while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
    {
      TableColumn column = enumerator.nextElement();
      String headerName = column.getHeaderValue().toString();
      JCheckBoxMenuItem cbmi = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(headerName, true);
      cbmi.addActionListener(this);

      column.setIdentifier(cbmi);

      menu.add(cbmi);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    JCheckBoxMenuItem source = (JCheckBoxMenuItem)e.getSource();
    boolean checked = source.getState();

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    int columnIndex = columnModel.getColumnIndex(source); // <<-- fails after removing the column
    System.out.printf("Checked: %b, column: %d%n", checked, columnIndex);
    TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(columnIndex);

    if (checked)
    {
      // add this column back to the table
      table.addColumn(column);
      int displayedColumns = getDisplayedColumns(columnModel);
      table.moveColumn(displayedColumns, displayedColumns-1);
    }
    else
    {
      // remove this column from the table
      table.removeColumn(column);
    }
  }

  private int getDisplayedColumns(TableColumnModel columnModel)
  {
    Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = columnModel.getColumns();
    int displayedCount = 0;
    while (columns.hasMoreElements())
    {
      displayedCount++;
    }
    return displayedCount;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that, once I remove the column, it is no longer in the TableColumnModel; I expected the column to be in the TableColumnModel but no longer in the JTable.

But I was mistaken: the method `TableColumnModel.getColumn(int index)` works when the column is displayed, and fails after the column is displayed.  When I examined the TableColumnModel instance in the debugger, it was clear the column had been removed from the model.

Is there a way to do what I want?  I can make a collection of columns to re-insert the one that is missing, but some of the documentation I've read led me to believe that the table is just a view of the model, and so I cling to the belief that the column is there somewhere.  Can anyone tell me where to find it?

---

Many thanks to camickr; I thought I would post the class I ended up with:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 * Holds representation of columns from the given JTable, including
 * a JMenu and its action routine for removing them and replacing
 * them in the table.  
 * <P>To use, create an instance with your table after
 * it has at least enough data to establish its columns.  Then use
 * getMenu() for an instance of JMenu, and put it on your menu bar.
 * The resulting menu will have checkboxes for all the columns, and
 * it handles their removal and addition.  No other code in the application
 * should remove or add columns; their added/removal state is maintained
 * in the SelectableColumns instance.
 * 
 * @author rcook
 */
public class SelectableColumns implements ActionListener
{
  JTable table = null;
  JMenu  menu  = null;    public JMenu getMenu() { return menu; }

  ArrayList<TableColumn> removedColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();

  public SelectableColumns(JTable table)
  { 
    this.table = table;
    menu = new JMenu("Columns");

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    Enumeration<TableColumn> enumerator = columnModel.getColumns();
    while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
    {
      TableColumn column = enumerator.nextElement();
      String headerName = column.getHeaderValue().toString();
      JCheckBoxMenuItem cbmi = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(headerName, true);
      cbmi.addActionListener(this);

      column.setIdentifier(cbmi);

      menu.add(cbmi);
    }
  }

  /**
   * A Checkbox menu item representing one column has been chosen; it 
   * could have been checked or unchecked.  Put the removed column
   * back into the table, or remove it from the table.
   */
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    JCheckBoxMenuItem source = (JCheckBoxMenuItem)e.getSource();
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    boolean checked = source.getState();
    TableColumn removedColumn = null;
    if (!checked)
    {
      // remove this column from the table
      int columnIndex = columnModel.getColumnIndex(source);
      //System.out.printf("Checked: %b, column: %d%n", checked, columnIndex);
      TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(columnIndex);
      table.removeColumn(column);
      removedColumns.add(column);
    }
    else
    {
      // add this column back to the table
      // first find the column in the list of removed columns
      for (TableColumn column: removedColumns)
      {
        if (column.getIdentifier().equals(source)) 
        { 
          removedColumn = column; 
          break; 
        }
      }

      // as long as we actually have a column, add it back to the
      // table
      if (removedColumn == null)
      {
        System.err.println("removedColumn not in the list...");
      }
      else
      {
        table.addColumn(removedColumn);
        int numDisplayed = columnModel.getColumnCount();
        table.moveColumn(numDisplayed-1, numDisplayed-2);  // move to next-to-last position
        removedColumns.remove(removedColumn);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I simply added a list of "removed columns", and use it to add back any removed column that is re-checked to be displayed.  I always add back to the next-to-last place; obviously that could be made more flexible for general use.  I've also thought of having a method that would display a dialog with the checkboxes, so a user could change the state of multiple columns at one time.  But for 100 lines of code, this does what I want right now and illustrates the principle I was looking for and that camickr kindly provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do what I want? I can make a collection of columns to re-insert the one that is missing,

Correct, you need to keep track of the TableColumns your remove. Your popup menu then needs to set the state of the check box depending on if the TableColumn is in the TableColumnModel or in your collection of removed TableColumns.

Or you could use the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) which already provides this functionality for you.

This implementation also attempts to track the position of the column when it was removed so it can be inserted back into the same place instead of just appending it to the end of the TableColumnModel.